# Ember DS.Store error while submitting form

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm a newbie to ember and I'm trying to create a basic sign-up form.

Relevant model:

```
App.NewUser = DS.Model.extend({
  user_name: DS.attr('string'),
  password: DS.attr('string'),
  confirm_password: DS.attr('string'),
  email: DS.attr('string'),
  first_name: DS.attr('string'),
  last_name: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

Relevant controller:

```
App.SignupController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  actions: {
    signup: function() {
        var data = this.getProperties('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'user_name', 'password', 'confirm_password');
        var newUser = this.store.createRecord('newUser', data);
        newUser.save();
    },
  },
});
```

When the "signup" action executes, I get the following error:

```
Error: Attempted to handle event `didSetProperty` on <App.NewUser:ember332:null> while in state root.deleted.saved. Called with {name: last_name, oldValue: undefined, originalValue: undefined, value: undefined}.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That was just an error copy-pasting the wrong code into stack overflow. I've edited accordingly.

Comment: are you attempting to modify it quickly thereafter?  It appears to work with that code, http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/121/edit

Comment: Um...I get the same error message in the console when I try that JSBin.

Comment: POST http://run.jsbin.com/newUsers 403 (Forbidden) ?

Comment: You are leaving fields blank?  And setting ED fields to undefined.

Comment: Yeah leaving fields blank seems to cause the issue. What is the proper way to handle blank fields then? I'm doing form validation on the server-side...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug, Ember Data is setting the record state incorrectly if you're setting a value to what it's currently set to (`undefined` on `createRecord`)

You'll want to either coerce your values into empty strings or not set undefined values while creating the record.

```
for(var key in data){
   if(!data[key]) delete data[key];
}
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/124/edit

https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1648